unable to update rows of information
Please direct me to another tread if there is a similar one already.
This an enquiry for
Data Scripts for Google Sheets
I am unable to input the data in the cells I would like to.
Below is the sequence to occur when I press 'run script'
Script collect information from Google Sheets.
Script computes what the new number should be.
Script input the newly calculated data into Sheet.
loops until it suppose to end. (not sure to use array length of when cell is empty)
Attached is a screenshot with comments on what they suppose to do.enter image description here
I tried using
var = somenumbers // to control the rows/columns i am trying to target and debugger stops it there
all the decalred numbers somehow ended up = 0
I have no idea what i am doing at this point. Attached iamge among a few methods I have tried to get the number to reference. (https://i.sstatic.net/t2Av9Nyf.jpg)
Any help will be much appreciated

Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow. I understand that you are trying to just sum up values from previous values to current values. Can you try sample data and a manually created result that you are expecting, this way the community will have a better understanding of your goal and how your code is supposed to work.
